# Custom searchview suggestions based on 3 strings

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api-3

I'm looking to implement custom Searchview suggestions. However I don't want them to change, I want the three suggestions to always be the same.

```
MatrixCursor mCursor = new MatrixCursor(threeGyms);

    CursorAdapter mCursorAdapter = new CursorAdapter(MapScreen.this, mCursor, 0) {
        @Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

        }
    };
    searchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(mCursorAdapter);
```

The three strings I want suggested are in the String[] threeGyms.

Is there any simple way of implementing this? The search bar is placed in a google map api activity.